# LinkedList can lead to unnecessary performance overhead if the List is randomly accessed

Tags: java

I have this my code:

```
  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default List<String> write() {
    return new LinkedList<>();
  }
```

And [DeepCode](https://www.deepcode.ai/) IntelliJ plugin indicates that *LinkedList can lead to unnecessary performance overhead if the List is randomly accessed*. And `ArrayList` should be used instead.

What is this performance overhead that LinkedList have over ArrayList? Is it really much of a difference as what DeepCode suggest?

Comment: It is the documented fact that indexed access to a `LinkedList` has computational complexity of *O(N)*. If you're not doing that, don't worry. If you are, use `ArrayList`. Why you would have a method called `write()` that returns an empty `List` remains a mystery.

Comment: Why are you using a `LinkedList` in the first place? Do you know what it is?

Comment: I disagree with the message. It is tendentious. Does it give an inverse message for `ArrayList` saying it can lead to unnecessary performance degradation if the `List` is inserted into ot deleted from frequently?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne this is actually Immutable https://immutables.github.io/ sorry I forgot to mention, that's why it returns an empty list, it's not empty actually when used.

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` have different performance characteristics as described in the JavaDoc. Inserting into a `LinkedList` is cheap, especially at the front and back. Traversing a `LinkedList` in sequence, e.g. with streams or `foreach`, is (relatively) cheap.

On the other hand, random access e.g. with `get(n)` is slow, as it takes `O(n)`.

`ArrayLists` on the other hand do random access in `O(1)`. Inserting on the other hand runs in *amortized constant time*:

> The `add` operation runs in *amortized constant* time, that is, adding n elements requires `O(n)` time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the `LinkedList` implementation.

The main advantage of `LinkedList` is that it allows for fast inserting and deletion at the front/end and via the iterator. A typical usage scenario is if you use the `LinkedList` as a `Queue` or `Deque` (it actually implements those two interfaces as well).

So, it depends on what you are doing. If you have frequent random access, use `ArrayList`. If you have frequent sequential access (via the iterator) and adding/removing from front/back, e.g. because you use it as a `Queue`, use `LinkedList`.

If you add at arbitrary positions, e.g. via `add(int index, E element)`, a `LinkedList` has to traverse the list first, making insertion `O(n)`, having no benefit over `ArrayList` (which has to shift the subsequent elements down and eventually resize the underlying array, which again, is *amortized* `O(n)` as well).

In practice, I'd only choose `LinkedList` if there is a clear need for it, otherwise I'd use `ArrayList` as the default choice. Note that if you know the number of elements, you can size an `ArrayList` properly and thus avoid resizing, making the disadvantages of `ArrayList` even smaller.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
- See also https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/some-java-list-benchmarks/ (thanks to @Leprechaun for providing this resource)

Comment: Your last sentence is the bottom line of it: If you have frequent random access, use ArrayList. If you have frequent sequential access, and insert at front/back, e.g. because you use it as a queue, use LinkedList.

Comment: @JanosVinceller Inserting at the front or back has nothing to do with it. If you insert via the iterator, it is *O(1)* wherever you do it.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne But *only* if you do it via the iterator. If you simply try to add in the middle you need to traverse first again and then insert. Inserting at front/back is *always* fast.